# cssRules object is missing css rules

Tags: html, css

I've got a "style" element with this rule:

```
#canvas {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background-color: none;
    border: none;
    width:300px;
    height:250px;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

now if i'm trying to access its css rules via:

```
StyleElem.sheet.cssRules[0].cssText
```

i'm getting:

```
#canvas { position: absolute; z-index: 100; left: 0px; top: 0px; border: none; width: 300px; height: 250px; user-select: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); overflow: hidden; }
```

now as you can see some rules has dissapeared like:
background-color
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
........
any idea why? and how to fix that?

Comment: Curious, do these options show up if you use a browser that requires them? It is possible those options get optimized out of the css since your browser most likely understands `user-select: none;`

Comment: I agree with @ChristianScillitoe and you can put a random background color to see if it appears.

Comment: the browser ignores rules that do not pertain to it.

Comment: `background-color: none;` - that’s not a valid _color_.

Comment: @ChristianScillitoe you're right , when i changed the background-color it reappeared in the cssRules. but i'm actually needs to access all rules like this because i'm using the browser parser to parse css from text and extract the rules and i'm loosing those rules like that, any suggestions?

Comment: set the background color to: `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);`. This way it should appear. What this does it sets the background color to transparent, so the same thing as "none"

Comment: @avidahan you could open the `.css` file for reading